# Ruby IDE in Ubuntu

Tags: 12.10, ruby, ide

Could you people help me by saying a good `Ruby compatible IDE in Ubuntu` and its installation and settings with Ruby environment? I really need that one.

I don't want Rails version,only Ruby 1.9.3.

I could not find from the software center also.

Thanks

Comment: @JorgeCastro only have shown there what are the IDEs available for ubuntu, but none of the configuration related topic is there. Thus here I have posted back

Comment: @PythonLikeYOU Your question asks *What is a good one?* not *what about configuration settings etc*, so it is a duplicate of the IDE question. We don't want many questions about IDE's spread over the whole site.

Comment: @Seth Yes, You are right- I just updated my decription. But I forgot to mention that. But still if you guys want I can delete my post.But in that case my trouble will not be reduced,still I am ready o delete my post.

Comment: I personally use [sublimetext 2](https://sublimetext.com/) and [redcar](https://github.com/redcar/redcar).

Comment: @PythonLikeYOU the install process are on the websites that I linked.

Comment: @jrg Okay does it support Ubuntu? Could you tell me the installation process also? I want an IDE ,not any text editor btw.

Comment: @PythonLikeYOU please stop reposting the same comment, the install instructions are in the links, they work on ubuntu, and they are a text editor with the features of an IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at Aptana Studio. It's available as standalone version or Eclipse Plugin. It provides many features for web development. It is really nice for PHP and Ruby. It also has Ruby On Rails features on board.

You can download it at http://www.aptana.com/.

Comment: in Ubuntu how to do that? guide me please.

Comment: Just download the zip-package on the website. Unpack the files, store the folder somewhere (for example in /opt) and launch the AptanaStudio3 file. This will start Aptana Studio.

Comment: Yes,but how would it communicate with ruby? That's my question actually? Is there any custom settings needed? [official site](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download) saying it is tested with ubuntu 9. But I am using latest version of Ubuntu.

Comment: It also works with newer Ubuntu versions. How should it communicate? If you edit/create ruby-files (.rb), it will use syntax highlighting for example. And it will use default ruby commands like "ruby". For that you need to install Ruby first.

Comment: Yes, I have Ruby 1.9.3 in place. but as you told in any place I can unpack it. Is it so? Or any specific folder I need to keep it ?

Comment: Where to keep my .rb files when will be working with it, and where should I place it? Can you provide a step - by - step approach help?

Comment: You can unpack it where you want. The best would be /opt (imho), but there you need sudo. You also can unpack it somewhere in you /home directory. If you have ruby installed, Aptana will use the standard ruby commands. Atana will also ask you for workspace or use a default workspace. The workspace is your folder for your projects/code.

Comment: Maybe this little how to helps http://www.samclarke.com/2012/04/how-to-install-aptana-studio-3-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin/ And here you can find some information about workspaces http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507989/aptana-studio-3-what-is-a-workspace

Comment: This might be helpful, I will give it a try. Post it within your answer, so that people can find it very quickly.

Comment: Atom IDE has Ruby language support; a core package called *language-ruby*.